# Adding custom attribute in Grav markdown content breaks it

Tags: php, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, grav, custom-attribute

Grav & markdown question here.

In [PHP Markdown Extra](https://michelf.ca/projets/php-markdown/extra/#attr-sup), Michel Fortin writes that we can use this kind of syntax:

```
## The Site ##      {.principal .eclat #le-site lang=en}
```

to add classes, id & custom attributes to an element (in this example, a heading).

But I can't find a mention of this in Github Flavoured Markdown doc or Grav doc.

And if adding a class or id is totally working in my Grav installation, adding a custom attribute is not. In fact it breaks my heading.

```
# My title {.my-class1 .my-class2 #my-id}
```

compiles perfectly to

```
<h1 class="my-class1 my-class2" id="my-id">My title</h1>
```

but

```
# My title {.my-class1 .my-class2 #my-id lang=fr}
```

compiles to

```
<h1>My title {.my-class1 .my-class2 #my-id lang=fr}</h1>
```

as if it was not recognized…

Is someone having the same problem as I?

Note: the Markdown Extra plugin is installed & activated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parsedown extra processor was not updated since two years and the proposed fixes aren't committed, so you can only use the class and the id shortcuts. See https://github.com/erusev/parsedown-extra/issues/100.

Comment: Ok, so this is an implementation problem, and as for now, nobody can do anything, except the Parsedown Extra processor mainteners :/ 

Thanks!

Comment: I think that the maintainer will merge in the next weeks (see https://github.com/erusev/parsedown-extra/pull/110).